# Why I get a nginx 404 when I pointing a Symlink to a path?

Tags: docker, nginx, symlink

I want to access a directory not containing in the docroot from nginx.

### The Situation:

**I've got a folder which contains files:**

*Command:*

```sh
ls -lah /var/www/
```

*Output:*

```sh
drwxr-x---.  2 docker-www docker-www    6 Jul 24 16:56 some_folder
```

**And I've got a path which should delivers the content from the folder above:**

*Command:*

```sh
ls -lah /var/www/typo3/releases/current/typo3-web/web/info/symlink
```

*Output:*

```sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 docker-www docker-www    32 Jul 24 16:56 symlink -> /var/www/some_folder
```

**My nginx config:**

```
root /usr/share/nginx/current/typo3-web/web;
...
location /info/symlink/ {
    allow all;
    autoindex on;
    disable_symlinks off;
}
```

### Problem:

The nginx delivers "404 Not Found"

### Things I've tried yet:

- Create a **normal** folder in */var/www/typo3/releases/current/typo3-web/web/info/* and it works. NGINX delivers the file index.
- Check the file permissions: the user docker-www has access to the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I have to mount the folder into the docker container by using another docker volume.